# How can I draw the switch in circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

While writing an article about RL circuits, I wanted to treat the periodicity of current establishment and rupture, I wanted to draw the following circuit.

```
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
 \draw (0,-2) to[vsource, l=$E$] (0,3);
 \draw (0,3) to[short, nos] (2,3);
 \draw (2,3) to[cute inductor=$(L)$] (2,0);
 \draw (2,0) to[R=$R$] (2,-2);
 \draw (0,-2) to[short] (2,-2);
 \draw (2,3) to[short] (4,3);
 \draw (4,3)--(4,-2)--(2,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

This what I want, and here what I've got !

[image]

Also when I want to write the internal resistance of the inductor `cute inductor=$(L,r)$` I get an error.
Where's the problem ?

Comment: See documentation for the `circuitikz` package: last example on the page 108.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

with use of the switch symbol `spdt` (see `circuitikz` package documentation,  page 108) and use default (`american`) style of circuits drawing :

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\node[spdt, rotate=90] (sw) {};
\draw   (sw.in)     to [L={$(L,r)$}] ++ (0,-2)
                    to [R=$R$] ++ (0,-2) coordinate (aux1)
        (sw.out 2)  node[above] {(2)}   to [short] ++ (+1,0) |- (aux1)
        (sw.out 1)  node[above] {(1)}   to [short] ++ (-1,0) coordinate (aux2)
                    to [vsource, a=$E$]    (aux2 |- aux1)
                    to [short] (aux1);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

For `european` style, you need to  add `circuitikz` option `european`:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
```

In this case result is the following:

[image]

However, if you like to have mix og the both styles, then MWE is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\node[spdt, rotate=90] (sw) {};
\draw   (sw.in)     to [L={$(L,r)$}] ++ (0,-2)
                    to [R=$R$, european] ++ (0,-2) coordinate (aux1)
        (sw.out 2)  node[above] {(2)}   to [short] ++ (+1,0) |- (aux1)
        (sw.out 1)  node[above] {(1)}   to [short] ++ (-1,0) coordinate (aux2)
                    to [vsource, a=$E$]    (aux2 |- aux1)
                    to [short] (aux1);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Comment: @jsbibra, yes, OP has such symbol for resistor, which is not consistent with symbol of inductance, which is american type ... . To consider OP option `european` for scheme, than inductance has different symbol.

Comment: @jsbibra, this detail I left to OP,

Comment: added +1 for the extra efforts

Answer (score 2):

And for the label, you have to add curly brackets INSIDE the $: ${(L,r)}$, otherwise the parser mess up.
It gives you finally:

````
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\node[spdt, rotate=90] (sw) {};
\draw   (sw.in)     to [L=${(L,r)}$] ++ (0,-2)
                    to [R=$R$, european] ++ (0,-2) coordinate (aux1)
        (sw.out 2)  node[above] {(2)}   to [short] ++ (+1,0) |- (aux1)
        (sw.out 1)  node[above] {(1)}   to [short] ++ (-1,0) coordinate (aux2)
                    to [vsource, a=$E$]    (aux2 |- aux1)
                    to [short] (aux1);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 1):

here is my contribution

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, cute inductors]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\node[spdt, rotate=90] (inter) {};
\draw   (inter.in)
    to [L, l=\mbox{$(L,r)$}] ++ (0,-2)
    to [R, l=$R$] ++ (0,-2) coordinate (aux1)
    (inter.out 2)  node[above] {(2)}
    to [short] ++ (+1,0) |- (aux1)
    (inter.out 1)  node[above] {(1)}   
    to [short] ++ (-1,0) coordinate (aux2)
    to [vsource, a=$E$]    (aux2 |- aux1)
    to [short] (aux1);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\mbox` to write the detail of the dipole L, r.

Being European, I insert the option `european` into the circuitikz package directly. As Zarko indicates, on the other hand, you must also add the option `cute inductors` to avoid obtaining a black rectangle as the inductor.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using a `cute spdt`, which allows for the wires to leave the nodes horizontally:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \node [cute spdt mid, rotate=90] (S) {};
    \draw (S.in) to [L=${(L,r)}$] ++ (0,-2)
                 to [R=$R$, european] ++ (0,-2) coordinate (B)
                 to [short] ++ (-1,0) coordinate (L)
                 to [vsource, l=$E$] (L |- S-out 1)
                 to (S-out 1) node[above] {(1)}
                 (S-out 2) node[above] {(2)} to [short] ++ (1,0) |- (B);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image: circuit with horizontal wires]